# How to handle preflight CORS requests on a Go server

Tags: go, cors, preflight

So I'm writing this RESTful backend in Go, which will be called with cross-site HTTP requests, i.e. from content served by another site (actually, just another port, but the same-origin policy kicks in, so here we are).

In this scenario, the user agent will, in some cases, send preflight OPTIONS requests to check if the actual request is safe to send.

My question is how to best deal with, and adequately respond to, these preflight requests in a Go context. The ways I have conceived don't feel very elegant, and I'm wondering if there's some other approach to this that I haven't thought of.

Using the standard `net/http` package, I can check the request method in the handler func, perhaps like this:

```
func AddResourceHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  switch r.Method {
  case "OPTIONS":
    // handle preflight
  case "PUT":
    // respond to actual request
  }
}
```

I can also use [Gorilla's](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) `mux` package, and register a preflight "OPTIONS" handler for each relevant URL path.

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/someresource/item", AddResourceHandler).Methods("PUT")
r.HandleFunc("/someresource/item", PreflightAddResourceHandler).Methods("OPTIONS")
```

Maybe the response to this question is simply: *Yup, those are your basic options.* But I thought there might be some best practice around this that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Yup, those are your basic options :) It would help to know what else you were expecting - are there other languages that handle it totally differently, for example?

Comment: Ah! Adding a preflight handler -- thank you so much for posting this!! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One simple way to separate out your logic and re-use the CORS handler you define would be to wrap your REST handler. For example, if you're using net/http and the `Handle` method you could always do something like:

```
func corsHandler(h http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if (r.Method == "OPTIONS") {
      //handle preflight in here
    } else {
      h.ServeHTTP(w,r)
    }
  }
}
```

You can wrap like this:

```
http.Handle("/endpoint/", corsHandler(restHandler))
```

Comment: Thanks, you put me on track! I already have an intercepting `corsHandler` that just smacks on default CORS headers before delegating to the "real" handler. By doing conditional delegation based on request method I got a somewhat DRY:er solution.

Comment: Shouldn't the argument be `h http.HandlerFunc`, not `h http.Handler`?

Comment: I found this answer very helpful after trying without success to use the Gorilla CORS function and a few other options.  Where the author has suggested "//handle preflight" I used these specific calls: ```log.Print("preflight detected: ", r.Header)w.Header().Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
   w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
   w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, DELETE, PUT")
   w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type")
   w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400")```

Comment: What's some typical logic to handle pre-flight? What does the browser want to see in a pre-flight response?

Comment: Not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests, though.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a snippet that worked for me:

```
addCorsHeader(res)
if req.Method == "OPTIONS" {
    res.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    return
} else {
    h.APIHandler.ServeHTTP(res, req)
}


func addCorsHeader(res http.ResponseWriter) {
    headers := res.Header()
    headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    headers.Add("Vary", "Origin")
    headers.Add("Vary", "Access-Control-Request-Method")
    headers.Add("Vary", "Access-Control-Request-Headers")
    headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Origin, Accept, token")
    headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST,OPTIONS")
}
```

Comment: You never need to allow the `Origin` header.

Answer (score 9):

I personally find it tedious to add preflight routes for every path that will get an `OPTIONS` request, so instead I simply add my handler to any `OPTIONS` method that the request multiplexer (Gorilla in this case) handles as follows:

```
router.Methods("OPTIONS").HandlerFunc(
    func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    myHttpLib.OptionsForBrowserPreflight(w, r)
})
```

Note though, that this should come before mapping other routes because if, *for example*, you have a path like `"/foo"` and you register that first without specifying any methods for that route, then an OPTIONS request to "/foo" would run instead of your pre-flight code because its the first match.

This way you can: (1) have just one routing registration for all pre-flights, and (2) have one handler to reuse code and apply logic/rules in a single place for OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 6):

[gorilla/handlers](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers) also has a nice CORS handler: [cors.go](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/blob/master/cors.go)

Example usage:

```
import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/users", UserEndpoint)
    r.HandleFunc("/projects", ProjectEndpoint)

    // Apply the CORS middleware to our top-level router, with the defaults.
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS()(r))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing worked from me from my Vue.js application so I did this.

```
cors := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*"}, //viper.GetString("ORIGIN_ALLOWED")
        AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token", "Authorization"},
        AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE"},
        Debug:            true,
        AllowCredentials: true,
    })

cors.Handler(corsMiddle())
```

```
func corsMiddle() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        if request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: how to import cors

Comment: @PrinceHamza use this `"github.com/rs/cors"`

Comment: `AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"}` is incompatible with `AllowCredentials: true`.