# Enable CORS in Golang

Tags: ajax, go, cors, cross-domain

Hi I'm implementing rest apis and for that I want to allow cross origin requests to be served.

What I am currently doing:

Go-server code on AWS:

```
func (c *UserController) Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ctx *rack.Context) {
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", r.Header.Get("Origin"))
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
...
...
c.render.Json(w,rsp, http.StatusOK)
return
}
```

Ajax code on localhost:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ip:8080/login',
        crossDomain: true, //set as a cross domain requests
        withCredentials:false,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Data " + data);
        },
    });
});
```

I am getting the following error on browser console:
***XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ip:8080/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 422.***

I tried adding preflight options:

```
func corsRoute(app *app.App) {
allowedHeaders := "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, Authorization,X-CSRF-Token"

f := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if origin := r.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", allowedHeaders)
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization")
    }
    return
}
app.Router.Options("/*p", f, publicRouteConstraint)
}
```

But it is not working.

What can be done to fix it.

Comment: Do you handle preflight OPTIONS request in your router?

Comment: No.. is that required?

Comment: Yes. Have a look to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972066/how-to-handle-preflight-cors-requests-on-a-go-server

Comment: 422 is `Unprocessable Entity ,The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.` maybe find in this direction?

Comment: If you're struggling with CORS in Go, check out https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jub0bs/fcors.

Answer (score 40):

I use `gorilla/mux` package to build Go RESTful API server, and client use JavaScript Request can work,

My Go Server runs at `localhost:9091`, and the Server code:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
//api route is /people, 
//Methods("GET", "OPTIONS") means it support GET, OPTIONS
router.HandleFunc("/people", GetPeopleAPI).Methods("GET", "OPTIONS")
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9091", router))
```

I find giving `OPTIONS` here is important, otherwise error will occur:

> OPTIONS http://localhost:9091/people 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> Failed to load http://localhost:9091/people: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9092' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

after allow `OPTIONS` it works great. I get the idea from [This Article](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/-Sh616lXNRE/Og85yH0VSU8J).

Besides, [MDN CORS doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) mention:

> Additionally, for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on server's data, the specification mandates that browsers **"preflight"** the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP **OPTIONS** request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method.

Following is the api **GetPeopleAPI** method, note in the method I give comment **//Allow CORS here By * or specific origin**, I have another similar answer explaining the concept of CORS [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47376760/4573839):

```
func GetPeopleAPI(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    //Allow CORS here By * or specific origin
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    // return "OKOK"
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("OKOK")
}
```

In the client, I use html with javascript on `localhost:9092`, and javascript will send request to server from `localhost:9092`

```
function GetPeople() {
    try {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:9091/people", false);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
        xhttp.send();
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
        alert(xhttp.response);
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
}
```

and the request can successfully get response `"OKOK"` .

You can also check response/request header information by tools like `Fiddler` .

Comment: to add multiple Access-Control-Allow-Headers use comma separated list like : w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Accept")

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer... It is very useful... It solved my issue

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for the clue - it's all in the header! I use only these golang headers on the server side:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Now works with this JQuery:

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.XXXXXXX.org/QueryUserID?u=juXXXXny&p=blXXXXXne',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(responseData);
            },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's a bad practice to allow CORS *

Comment: @V.Dalechyn oh yeah - so then what's the "right" way if you have a public api that people can use?

Comment: @alex Did anyone mention that the route is public to call from any origin? If Author tries to make ajax requests out of the browser locally he has to do it through proxy to fool his browser. CORS has to allow only specified origins or someone can post a request from a phishing site, retrieve JWT and proceed with money withdrawal for example

Comment: @V.Dalechyn not in this case - but stating "it's bad practice" doesn't cover all use cases.

Comment: @alex why not in this case? OP is implementing login controller and triggers fetch with ajax on html page inside <script></script>.

Comment: Note that you need to set these headers **before** writing to `w`.

Answer (score 9):

You can check this out https://github.com/rs/cors

This would handle the `Options` Request as well

Answer (score 9):

GO SERVER SETTING :

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
)


  func Cors(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=ascii")
  w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type,access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-headers")
          w.Write([]byte("Hello, World!"))
  }

  func main() {
  mux := http.NewServeMux()
  mux.HandleFunc("/plm/cors",Cors)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8081", mux)
}
```

Client JQUERY AJAX SETTING :

```
<head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
       </script>
</head>
<body>

              <br> Please confirm to proceed : <button class="myConfirmButton1">Go!!</button>

             <div id="loader1" style="display:none;">loading...</div>
             <div id="loader2" style="display:none;">...done</div>
             <div id="myFeedback1"></div>

          <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".myConfirmButton1").click(function(){
              $('#loader1').show();
              $.ajax({
                url:"http://[webserver.domain.com:8081]/plm/cors",
                dataType:'html',
                headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-headers"},
                type:'get',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                $('#loader1').hide();
                $('#loader2').show();
                $('#myFeedback1').html( data );
                        },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                $('#loader1').hide();
                $('#myFeedback1').html( errorThrown );
                alert("error" + errorThrown);
                        }
                });
           });
          });
          </script>
</body>
```

Client TEST REQUEST with curl and obtained response :

curl -iXGET http://[webserver.domain.com:8081]/plm/cors

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ascii
Date: Wed, 17 Jan 2018 13:28:28 GMT
Content-Length: 13

Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 9):

For allowing [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) your server should to catch all [Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) that's browser sends before real query with OPTIONS method to the same path.

First way is managing this manually by something like this:

```
func setupCORS(w *http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    setupCORS(&w, req)
    if (*req).Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }

    // process the request...
}
```

The second way is use ready to third party pkg like https://github.com/rs/cors

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write([]byte("{\"hello\": \"world\"}"))
    })

    // cors.AllowAll() setup the middleware with default options being
    // all origins accepted with simple methods (GET, POST). See
    // documentation below for more options.
    handler := cors.AllowAll().Handler(mux)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's important to have the OPTIONS check since CORS check uses OPTIONS. If HTTP request OPTIONS failed, it would fail the CORS too.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to all the great answers: instead of setting the headers in every handler you probably want to use the [appHandler](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) pattern:

```
type Handler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) *Error

func (fn Handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    if e := fn(w, r); e != nil { // e is *appError, not os.Error.
        http.Error(w, e.Message, e.Code)
    }
}

func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *Error {
   ...
   return nil
}

r.Handle("/login", Handler(Login))
```

Answer (score 4):

i have been facing the same issue lately. and i found out that only setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` didnt fixed my issue. the problem i had was the fact that browser first sends a `OPTIONS` request

so i had to check for `OPTIONS` requests and send ok response to fix this issue. and doing this actually fixed most of my cros related problems.

sample code of how i did is listed below

---

This is my server side middleware whcih is responsible for handling all the `CROS` related things

```golang
func CORSMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") // change this later
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS")

        if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            w.WriteHeader(204)
            return
        }

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

---

for my fronted i usually use react framework. and below is a example code of me creating a post. and how i would usually use this in fronted.

( also for my forms im using formik here )

```js
  <Formik
              initialValues={{ title: "", slug: "" }}
              validate={(values) => {
                const errors = {};
                if (!values.title) {
                  errors.title = "Required";
                } else if (!values.slug) {
                  errors.slug = "Required";
                }
                return errors;
              }}
              onSubmit={(resp, { setSubmitting }) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  var encodedPost = btoa(value);
                  resp.post = encodedPost;
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2));
                  const cookies = new Cookies();
                  let authtoken = cookies.get("auth");

                  /* sending the request */
                  var myHeaders = new Headers();
                  myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${authtoken}`);
                  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

                  var requestOptions = {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: myHeaders,
                    body: JSON.stringify(resp),
                  };

                  fetch(
                    "http://localhost:4000/api/v1/post/create",
                    requestOptions
                  )
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((result) => {
                      console.log(result);
                      alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                      alert(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
                    });

                  setSubmitting(false);
                }, 400);
              }}
            >
```

Comment: do we need to call the CORSMiddleware function ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok this problem gave me some issues but found a fix u have to use

```
github.com/gorilla/handlers
```

along with the gollila/mux lib

so here is a snippet

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
header := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"})
methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"})
origins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
api := r.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
api.Handle("/route", function).Methods("GET", "OPTIONS")
r.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _, _ = fmt.Fprint(w, "hello")
})

err := http.ListenAndServe(":9000", handlers.CORS(header, methods, origins)(r))

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

this should fix ur problem

Answer (score 2):

1. **First** : cors

   ```
   svc.Handle("/", restAPI.Serve(nil))
   ```
2. **After**, I fix: Handle -> HandleFunc

   ```
   svc.HandleFunc("/", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        setupHeader(rw, req)
        if req.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            return
        }
        restAPI.Serve(nil).ServeHTTP(rw, req)
        return
    })



    func setupHeader(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
           rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
           rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
           rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
           rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
api := router.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter()
api.HandleFunc("/getLastDateOfAMonth", lastday.Handler).Methods(http.MethodPost)
c := cors.New(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins:   []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "DELETE", "POST", "PUT"},
})
handler := c.Handler(router)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3001", handler))
```

Please check this -> [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request#:~:text=A%20CORS%20preflight%20request%20is,Headers%20%2C%20and%20the%20Origin%20header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request#:%7E:text=A%20CORS%20preflight%20request%20is,Headers%20%2C%20and%20the%20Origin%20header).

We all face CORS issue ->
Fix -> The Backend server should Accept CORS. Add cors to your backend application. So that it understand CORS on Preflight request from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just copy code randomly, this is a complicated issue, you need to understand it first.

There are two scenarios:

**First**: if you are using a simple HTTP GET request, then you can simply add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the response header, and it will work.

**Second**: If you are using a POST request, and you need to add some **request headers**, then you need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` to the **response header**, and you need to handle the OPTIONS request sent by the browser. Because for some POST requests, the browser will first send an OPTIONS request to the server to ask if it allows cross-origin requests. If the server does not allow it, then the browser will not send the real request.

You can find more details about this: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

For example, my backend API needs the client to bring a request header `Authorization: xxx` when sending HTTP requests, then I need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Authorization` or `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` to the response header, so that the browser will bring this request header when sending HTTP requests. Besides, I need to handle the OPTIONS request sent by the browser.

This is the logic in my codes:

```golang
func (s *Server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    enableCors(&w)
    // Handle CORS preflighted request sent by browser.
    if (*r).Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }

    s.mux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func enableCors(w *http.ResponseWriter) {
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS")
    // We need to allow the Authorization header to be sent to the backend.
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400")
}
```

Hope it will help.

---

BTW, you can check the cors error message in the browser console, it will tell you what is wrong.

```bash
# Apparently there is no server to handle the OPTIONS request. 
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. 

# This is because the backend server does not allow the content-type request header.
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/api/chat' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: `(*r).Method == "OPTIONS"` is too restrictive a condition. Not all `OPTIONS` requests are preflight requests. See https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using a react app as "source of http calls".
I tried to use many of suggestions in this thread, but apparently none of them worked.

Then I looked at the browser network develop tab, when then i realized that react sends an OPTION request, ant at request header there was 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type,user-agent'

At this moment, i added "user-agent" in the response header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", and then all worked.
The "final" code was:

```
c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With,user-agent")
```

[react](/questions/tagged/react) [cors](/questions/tagged/cors)