# Golang No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, go, cookies

I am trying to test if I am in domain A, can domain A client send domain B cookie to domain B.

Here is my golang code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
)

func setCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
    cookie := http.Cookie{Path: "/test_receive_cookie", Name: "test_cors", Value: "test_cors", Expires: expiration}
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Success")
}

func receiveCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.Cookies())

    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    for _, cookie := range r.Cookies() {
        data[cookie.Name] = cookie.Value
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(data)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/set_cookie", setCookie)
    http.HandleFunc("/test_receive_cookie", receiveCookie)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8012", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

I first hit `http://localhost:8012/set_cookie` , then I open a html file containing a javascript using this [library](https://github.com/naugtur/xhr)

```
        this._xhr.get(
            "http://localhost:8012/test_receive_cookie", 
            { headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }},
            function(err, resp) {
                console.log(resp);
                console.log(err);
            });
```

The following happened

1. Browser returns

`Failed to load http://localhost:8012/test_receive_cookie: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

2. My server print `[]` from `fmt.Println(r.Cookies())`
3. If I hit `http://localhost:8012/test_receive_cookie` I can see the cookie I set gets print out on browser, but when I open a html that calls the endpoint the server will have empty cookie

My questions is how can I pass the cookie back to `http://localhost:8012/test_receive_cookie` using client code?

Am I missing some configuration code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need your Go server to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers, the client can't provide them (see [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)).

If you update your server to add this header, the client will stop throwing an error.

### Example

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

#### Reference:

[Enable CORS in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507065/enable-cors-in-golang)

Comment: So the no origin error is now gone, but the `println` for `r.Cookies` returns a empty array. I am not exactly sure why does it do that. Since I expect that if the domain name and path name matches, the cookies should be auto attached.

Comment: Here is my request `&{GET /test_receive_cookie HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Accept:[*/*] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate, br] Accept-Language:[en-US,en;q=0.9] Here is my request. User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36] Connection:[keep-alive] Pragma:[no-cache] Cache-Control:[no-cache] Origin:[null]] {} <nil> 0 [] false localhost:8012 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:61817 /test_receive_cookie <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc420014600}`