# How do you make a request from client to server locally using fetch without getting an opaque response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, go, cors, fetch-api

I'm running a react app on `localhost:3000`, and a go server on `localhost:8000`.

When I make a `request` from the client using `fetch` - the response is opaque so I'm not able to access the data.

**How do I make a valid cross-origin request?**

**client:**

```
componentWillMount() {
  const url = 'https://localhost:8000/api/items'
  fetch(url, { mode: 'cors' })
  .then(results => {
    return results.json()
  }).then(data => {
  let items = data;
  this.setState({items})
  })
}
```

**server:**

```
func GetItems(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    items := getItems()
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(items)
}
```

From what I've read - it's expected that requests made across resources should be opaque - but for local development - how do you get access to the JSON?

After looking at the definitions for request types I found this:

> cors: Response was received from a valid cross-origin request. Certain
>   headers and the body may be accessed.

I think I need to set up a valid cross-origin request.

**I got it!**

This question helped resolve how to set up CORS in golang: [Enable CORS in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507065/enable-cors-in-golang)

**3 key things here:**

- Set the mode in the client request to `cors`
- Set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the server to `*`
- Call `.json()` on the result in the client, and in a 
  following promise you can access the data.

Comment: What do you mean by opaque?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type
it's a specific type of response.

Comment: I see - so why is mode set to `no-cors`?

Comment: Just got to changing that - but still no luck - request is opaque. I've tried setting the headers per the answer below as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")    
w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
```

You can try to add them in the handleFunc

Comment: The only required one FWIW in my case was: 
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")