# Go: How to disable CORS using gqlgen graphql implementation?

Tags: go, cors, graphql

I am using [gqlgen](https://gqlgen.com/) as GraphQL server. I connect to this server from the front end application using [Apollo client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/).

Everything works correctly if I compile the front end code and serve it as static content by the GraphQL server.

**Problem:**

During development I have my Go-based GraphQL API running on `http://localhost:8080` and I have the front end code on a separate server runing on `http://localhost:3000`. This way I get CORS errors.

I managed to fix the issue on the front end side by specifying `no-cors` option while creating the client, but the back end still gives 400s to my requests.

**Question:**

How to disable CORS in a gqlgen-based GraphQL API?

**Code:**

```
config := gql.Config{Resolvers: &gql.Resolver{}}
handler := handler.GraphQL(gql.NewExecutableSchema(config))
http.Handle("/query", handler)
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

The full server side code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/Shpota/skmz/blob/master/server/server.go).

**What I've tried**:

I followed [the solution from the documentation](https://gqlgen.com/recipes/cors/) which didn't work. I checked a couple of solutions on StackOverflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507065/enable-cors-in-golang), however they give a library specific solutions which don't feet in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it should be just enough if you set up this simple middleware

```golang
func cors(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        h(w, r)
    }
}

...
http.Handle("/query", cors(handler))
...
```

Also, I think it would be good to tune this accordingly on environments other than development.