# Running into CORS error with any HTTP call regardless of it being handled on the server

Tags: http, go, cors

I have a simple server written in Go. I then have a simple Nextjs app that acts as the frontend of my project. The issue is that whenever I try to fetch the backend from the frontend, the *normal* CORS error pops out.

Now, I know that the frontend does a preflight call with HTTP OPTIONS and it checks headers and so on, but after looking at dozens of StackOverflow posts with what seemed to be a solution, nothing worked.

This is the source code

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type ClassReturn struct {
    Errcode int         `json:"errcode"`
    Message string      `json:"message"`
    Data    interface{} `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    router(r)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}

func router(r *mux.Router) {
    r.HandleFunc("/get", corsHandler(handleOutput)).Methods("GET", "OPTIONS")
    r.HandleFunc("/post", corsHandler(handleOutput)).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")
}

func corsHandler(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            log.Print("preflight detected: ", r.Header)
            w.Header().Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
            w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
            w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, DELETE, PUT")
            w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type")
            w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400")
            return
        } else {
            handleOutput(w, r)
        }
    }
}

func handleOutput(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(ClassReturn{
        Errcode: 0,
        Message: "stuff endpoint",
        Data:    r.Method,
    })
}
```

This is the console message I get when fetching the go endpoint (for the get endpoint, but I do get the same for the post endpoint)

`localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/get' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

In the network tab I get the failed HTTP Request with GET + Preflight blocked by CORS

Neither a POST nor a GET call works, nor does it if I change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from `http://localhost:3000` to `*`

I tried different things, like those

- rs/cors
- github.com/gorilla/handlers
- [How to handle preflight CORS requests on a Go server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972066/how-to-handle-preflight-cors-requests-on-a-go-server)
- [Making golang Gorilla CORS handler work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985920/making-golang-gorilla-cors-handler-work)
- [Enable CORS in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507065/enable-cors-in-golang)
- https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/golang-cors-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/
- [CORS on golang server & javascript fetch frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485248/cors-on-golang-server-javascript-fetch-frontend)
- [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

But none of those above have worked.

I have also asked on the Discord server of Go but they prompt me to use these very solutions I have above, which don't work

If anyone knows a possible solution to my issue I would be delighted

Comment: Update the question by providing the specific CORS error message that your browser is showing. And also do include the browser's network console output for the failing requests.

Comment: And have you tried running your Go program with gorilla's [CORS middleware](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#handling-cors-requests)? Does that fail the same way? With same error?

Comment: I have updated the question with the specific CORS error printed in the console by the browser. I have also tried to use gorilla's CORS middleware, but I get the same result

Comment: What happens when you do a curl request? `curl -v -X OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/get`? Do you see the headers set by your `corsHandler`? Can you share the output of that curl command in the question?

Comment: I do not see all the headers I set (or at least not the Allow-Access-Control-Origin). This is the output after running the curl command in the CMD
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> OPTIONS /get HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 12 Nov 2022 14:08:44 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Comment: So the problem is that the code you have shown is not the code you are running. I have just now copied and compiled the code you have shown, ran it, did the curl command as in the comment, and I do see all the headers. See https://imgur.com/SLnC3BB

Comment: Check your ports, perhaps some older version of your program, or a completely separate program, is already running and listening on port `8000` and replying to those requests. Btw. I hope you do know you need to recompile a Go program if you make changes to it, right? Go is not like PHP. (I'm only bringing this up because I've seen others here on SO make that assumption)

Comment: I have recompiled my program and I can see all my headers on the CMD. But then my question is: Why am I seeing all those headers on the CMD call, but when my frontend does the fetch (GET/POST + OPTIONS) it does return a CORS error?

I have retried running the frontend after I recompiled the Go program

Comment: The CORS error will be different, for some other reason than "origin". If your browser sends a `OPTIONS` request to `http://localhost:8000/get` and it receives a response that *does* contain the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ...` header, it will not print out an error message identical to the one you have added to the question. Otherwise it would be lying to you.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

```golang
func corsHandler(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Print("preflight detected: ", r.Header)
        w.Header().Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
        w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
        w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, DELETE, PUT")
        w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type")
        w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400")

        // continue with my method
        handleOutput(w, r)
    }
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

After some checks (and help from [@mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva)), I found out that my frontend was not entering the `if` in the code, so my HTTP call was not OPTIONS, but directly GET. However, due to the CORS policy, headers were never set for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, so my call was failing.

Removing the control (`if r.Method == "OPTIONS"`) allowed the backend to always set headers so even on simple calls, my fetch would not fail

**SIDE NOTE**

There is a necessity to make a little side note here. Usually, it is strange to HTTP GET to make a Preflight request (for CORS). It is stated and well documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) that `Some requests don't trigger a CORS preflight.` `XMLHttpRequest and fetch can submit simple requests to any origin`. Now, I was using axios in my Next.js project, so  it was using a XMLHttpRequest. `the server still must opt-in using Access-Control-Allow-Origin to share the response`

This was written in the article linked above and should be a key reference when building a frontend with a backend, both in a localhost/development environment.

**ANOTHER SIDE NOTE**

I lost several hours of my time figuring out why adding custom headers was breaking CORS. The answer was in front of my eyes, as the CORS Policy "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" did not have the correct headers I sent on request. Considering I use "Authorization: Bearer ***", if I do not do like this, CORS breaks;

```
w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, content-type")
```

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) helped me a lot

I hope this clears any doubt, feel free to improve this answer

Comment: Rather than writing your own CORS middleware (which error-prone), you'd be better off using an existing (and proven) one. You'd save yourself a headache.